# Need to display records by joining two tables and the records should be Unique

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the two tables `STUDENT` and `TaskEffort`.

Many students have worked on same tasks. For a particular task the name of the students and effort should be considered.

The STUDENT table contains `studentid`, `firstName` and `lastName`.

The TaskEffort table contains `taskid`, `studentid` and `Effort`

I need to display the taskid, first name, last name, effort, for those who worked on a particular task.

This is one of the queries I tried, but this is not working.

```
SELECT t.id, s.firstname, s.lastname, t.effort 
FROM taskeffort t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN student s ON t.id = 4 AND s.studentid = t.studentid
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: define not working.. also sample data and ddl

Comment: You say student has the column firstname and lastname, but the query uses another column studentid...?

Comment: @jarlh the student table has 3 columns, sorry had missed it.

Comment: @amdixon firstname and the lastname column are null when I run my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.id, s.firstname,s.lastname, t.effort 
FROM taskeffort t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN student s ON s.studentid = t.studentid 
WHERE t.id = 4;
```

Comment: @jarlh have no idea about the person who down voted, is this query wrong?

Comment: Looks fine to me. But you could add an explanation why this should work better than the original query.

Comment: @jarlh I dont have access yet for votes and have no clue who has down voted, looking into your can you tell me what will where clause will do here?

Comment: @jarlh Just ran this query got the Result as I expected. Can I know why did my AND condition fail to get this.

Comment: @fei Just ran this query got the Result as I expected. Can I know why did my AND condition fail to get this.

Comment: When t.id = 4 is in the ON clause the LEFT JOIN is evaluated with t.id = 4, then non-matching t rows are added... When in WHERE clause, only t.id = 4 rows are selected.

Answer (score 1):

First the design is not accurate.
You said that  "Many students must have worked on same task" but your design is 
1-many students. It means that each task has only one student. You need to change the design to support you requirements.
this relation is many-to-many. Student can be assigned to many tasks and tasks may have been assigned to many students.
Add a third table called `taskAssignments` with columns: `student_id,task_id` and remove `student_id` column from `TaskEffort`.
Then run this query:

```
 SELECT t.id, s.firstname, s.lastname, t.effort 
    FROM TaskEffort t
    LEFT JOIN taskAssignments  ta ON t.id=ta.task_id
    LEFT JOIN student s ON s.studentid = ta.studentid
    WHERE  t.id = 4
```

Comment: this is a bit complicated, dint run the query. Looks like it should work. Any other simpler queries ?